# Vue JS - Conditional keyup.enter is not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, keyup, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to implement a conditional keyup event, however keyup.enter doesn't get fired when I implement it conditionally using a computed property for @[listenToKeyup].

```
<template>
   <div>
      <input @[listenToKeyup]="manageSearch"
             v-model="input"
             class="form-input"/>
   </div>
</template>
export default {
    props: {
      skipSearch: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: false,
        default: false
      },
      callback: {
        required: false
      },
    },
  setup(props, {emit}) {
      const input = ref('');

      const listenToKeyup = computed(() => props.skipSearch ? 'keyup.enter' : 'keyup');

      function manageSearch() {
        clearTimeout(searchTimeout)
        searchTimeout = setTimeout(props.callback(input.value), debounce);
      }

  return {
      input,
      listenToKeyup,
      manageSearch,
  };

  }
```

In this example, props.skipSearch is registered as true in another component and in fact 'manageSearch' does not get fired, whereas in other components where its false, it is fired. This means that the condition in listenToKeyup is being determined, however keyup.enter is not being fired. If I try to add the event without the condition '@keyup.enter="manageSearch"', it works as it should, so there isn't an issue with that either.

Can someone kindly show me what I'm doing wrong, please?

Comment: As stated in my deleted answer: `input` is returned but never defined

Comment: Input is also defined. I just thought of showing the code relevant to the specific issue not to clutter the question.

Comment: okay okay. you might be suprised how many issues are resolve because of typos

Comment: Certainly, happens to me all the time. But in this particular case it feels like there is something wrong. it seems that dynamic arguments with modifiers don't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the [event-modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers).

Dynamic events are possible but modifiers are not supported.

You would have to change your logic to what @Boussadjra Brahim was almost suggesting just with the difference that the modifier has to be written manually:

```
//manage Search
function manageSearch(event) {
  if (!props.skipSearch|| ["Enter"].includes(event.key)) {
    //do your thing
  }
}
```

### [Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-keyup-skip-search-jsdvc?file=/src/App.vue:422-588)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the example you provided why would I need the computed property keyModifiers exactly?

Comment: @thelandog actually forgot to delete that. you can ignore that thats from previous tries to get it run and finding out what is supported and what isn't. I've deleted it